# rails create method creating "unsaved" nil records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2 and the enumerize gem for my models (https://github.com/brainspec/enumerize)

I have a model User associated with an Items model defined as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    enumerize :type, :in => %w(toys clothing electronics)
end
```

the Item model was later upgraded to have an additional type

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    enumerize :type, :in => %w(toys clothing electronics food)
end
```

I fire up the console but when I try to do this:

```
u = User.first
u.items.create(type:'food')
```

I get this query:

```
    SELECT 1 AS one FROM "items" WHERE ("items"."type" = 'food' AND "items"."user_id" = 1) LIMIT 1
ROLLBACK
```

and when I try `user.items`

I see a record that has everything nil (id, item.type) but when I exit the console the nil record is gone.

However, if I create a record with a type in the previously defined array, the record saves just fine. Is there something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
u.items.create!(type:'food')
```

The bang will raise an exception if your item is not created. This should reveal your problem. Most likely a validation one.